# How to play video loop smoothly in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I have to play video loop (2 second HD quality), and there is problem with playing video from the begining because method seek(0) always freeze Flash Player for a moment. There is now way to avoid this problem.
I have an idea, to play 2 netstreams in 2 separeted workers, but dont know how to share stage to do this ;[.

Comment: There isn't, but you can always convert the video into a .swf and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem.
i have embed the flv video in swf and play it in time line .
with embed vido you can loop it smoothly, this is a good solution in some cases.

(unconditionally embedding the video in swf have performance issue increased when ever your project become more complicated.
another issue is  the swf file size become larger and larger
)